# How can i show a from name instead of email address using sendgrid in GCP composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sendgrid, google-cloud-composer

Following the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#notification) i am trying to send email using sendgrid in my cloud composer. I set up the variables SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM and SENDGRID_API_KEY . I want that the email should show the friendly name as from name rather than complete email address. I am using the Airflow Emailoperator

Comment: Do you sign in to SendGrid in with your SendGrid credentials and you[use the Settings, Tags and Build tabs to design and configure your email](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-email-with-marketing-campaigns/#create-a-single-send) in the SendGrid UI?

Comment: Please share more details. Also, please explain how this is related to [tag:composer-php]

Comment: Yes i signed into Sendgrid and got my SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM and SENDGRID_API_KEY.

Comment: Can't you just use SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM variable to whatever it is you want ?

Comment: Seems that  the [Email Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.9/_modules/airflow/operators/email_operator.html) has no  options to configure the `SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM` with a  friendly name , I suggest you to ask for this inprovement in  the [Airflow Improvements Proposals](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Airflow+Improvements+Proposals)